# convert dataframe column of list to comma separated string in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I've a dataframe `df1`

```
id     city       year
1       LA        [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2026]
2       FL        []
3       TX        [2012, 2013, 2014]
4       NY        [2012]
```

How can I convert the column `year` that contains list into comma separated string?

Desired result:

```
id     city       year
1      LA         2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016
2      FL         none
3      TX         2012, 2013, 2014
4      NY         2012
```

Note: The datatype of column `year` is string now.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
df["year"] = df["year"].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(map(str, x)))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   id city                          year
0   1   LA  2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2026
1   2   FL                              
2   3   TX              2012, 2013, 2014
3   4   NY                          2012
```

---

Or for `none` string:

```py
df["year"] = (
    df["year"].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(map(str, x))).replace("", "none")
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   id city                          year
0   1   LA  2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2026
1   2   FL                          none
2   3   TX              2012, 2013, 2014
3   4   NY                          2012
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `explode` then `groupby`

```
df.year = df.year.explode().astype(str).groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
df.loc[:, 'year'] = df.year.apply(str).replace('[\[\]]', '', regex=True)
```